TypeScript checking extra file that not specified in "files"
This is my tsconfig.json below, in this file I specified check only on specific file types, but TypeScript is checking other files.
I tried "includes", "excludes" but still the same problem happens.
Is there any option to run a specific file?
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./frontend/src/types"],
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": false,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["./frontend/src/common/*"],
      "@features/*": ["./frontend/src/components/features/*"],
      "@utilities/*": ["./frontend/src/components/utilities/*"],
      "@config/*": ["./frontend/src/config/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./frontend/src/components/*"],
      "@icons/*": ["./frontend/src/icons/*"],
      "@resource/*": ["./frontend/src/resource/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["./frontend/src/pages/*"],
      "@static/*": ["./frontend/src/static/*"],
      "@pro/*": ["./pro/frontend-pro/src/*"]
    }
  },
  "files": [
    "frontend/src/AppRoutes.tsx",
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "frontend/**/*.tsx"],
  "types": ["cypress", "node", "@4tw/cypress-drag-drop", "vite/client"]
}


